# Angular HTTP Params Returning Array instead of duplicate in get request

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http

I am trying to make multiple params value for single value in Angular get request, but it returning array for the value here is my code.

```
let params = new HttpParams;
let prefectures = [01, 02] //dynamic array of numbers
for(let pre of prefectures){
  params = params.append('prefecturesCode', pre);
}
```

here is the request code

```
return this.http
  .get(this.replaceBaseUrl(url), {
    headers,
    params: params
  })
```

I am getting this url

```
http://localhost:3003/endpoint?prefecturesCode=02,03
```

But what I need is like this

```
http://localhost:3003/endpoint?prefecturesCode=02&prefecturesCode=03
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the expected URL is not a standard, you can stick to default behavior and split the prefecturesCode value with a comma in your API. Otherwise, if it is a requirement then you may loop through the dynamic array, create and update the string variable, and append it to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need to pass a list of value in a query parameter the right way is

```
http://localhost:3003/endpoint?prefecturesCode=02,03
```

Think, for example, in node.js, when **Express** parse the query parameters in request it store in the **params** object which have a property with the name of the parameter. Thereforce you will get only the value 03 or an error if you send the same parameter twice.

Hope this can help you.